# Pass django templatetag return value in if statement

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I want to use the return value of my templatetag in if statement.

This is the templatetag

```
# validate_bookmark.py
from django import template
from user.models import Bookmark

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def validate_bookmark(post, user):
    if Bookmark.objects.filter(user=user, post=post).first() != None:
        return True
    return False
```

Template

```
{% load validate_bookmark %}

{% if (validate_bookmark post_obj request.user) == True %} <!-- Something like this -->
<button data-postpk="{{i.pk}}" class="**fw-bold** bookmarkBtn mx-3 n-border-outline n-border-outline far fa-bookmark px-0 py-0" style="font-size: 1.1rem;"></button>
{% else %}
<button data-postpk="{{i.pk}}" class="bookmarkBtn mx-3 n-border-outline n-border-outline far fa-bookmark px-0 py-0" style="font-size: 1.1rem;"></button>
```

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) you can store the results of a template tag in a template variable using the `as` argument, using that stored variable you can easily use it in the `if` tag:

```
{% validate_bookmark post_obj request.user as is_valid_bookmark %}
{% if is_valid_bookmark %}
<button data-postpk="{{i.pk}}" class="**fw-bold** bookmarkBtn mx-3 n-border-outline n-border-outline far fa-bookmark px-0 py-0" style="font-size: 1.1rem;"></button>
{% else %}
<button data-postpk="{{i.pk}}" class="bookmarkBtn mx-3 n-border-outline n-border-outline far fa-bookmark px-0 py-0" style="font-size: 1.1rem;"></button>
{% endif %}
```